# Why are new sheets not being created in the workbook? Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

TL;DR - I want to populate a brand new workbook with multiple sheets named after the values in a list I have. After running, there is only one sheet. It is populated correctly. I believe the error is in my `write_to_excel` function, shown below.

I am working with a workbook containing inventory and prices for products. There are multiple sheets, each one for a unique supplier. I would like to make a new excel workbook with the same sheet format (each supplier with its own sheet, no particular order).

I have a dictionary called "price_list", which contains product names as the key and their corresponding prices as the value. This list is initialized within a for loop and is therefore reset for each new supplier. `store_supplier_names` is a list filled with the names of suppliers which was previously loaded into the list.

I have printed (as shown below) `price_list` and `store_supplier_names` and they populate/iterate as they are supposed to.

```py
x = 0
for supplier in store_supplier_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(origin_file_1, sheet_name=supplier, skiprows=3)
    
    # initialized as empty so it is ready to store products for each individual supplier
    price_list = {}
   
    # iterate through each supplier's dataframe object to create the values to populate price_list
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if df.iloc[index, 2] not in price_list:
            price_list[df.iloc[index, 2]] = 'test'

    # print(price_list)
    # print(store_supplier_names[x])

    write_to_excel(price_list, store_supplier_names[x])
    x += 1
```

I send `price_list` and `store_supplier_names[x]` (which are populated correctly and take the correct value respectively) to a helper method which will write the new workbook.

```py
def write_to_excel(price_list, supplier):
    pricing = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(price_list, orient='index')
    pricing.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=supplier)
    writer.save()
```

Since this function is being called repeatedly in a for loop, my thinking is that each time the correct price_list and supplier name will be sent, which will be used to create a sheet named after the supplier and fill it with the products.

However, after running, only the very first supplier and its products are added to the workbook. The contents for this supplier are correct. I'm just unsure why the new sheets are not created.

Thanks in advance for any advice and help provided. :)

Comment: If you are using XlsxWriter as the Excel engine then you need to move the `save()` outside the function since that will close the file and you won't be able to write to it again.

Comment: That did it, thanks!